# Windows 8 Metro Style Horizontal design

Tags: controls, windows-8, windows-runtime, horizontal-scrolling, semantic-zoom

I would like to ask which controls can be used to create a design similar to the built-in Weather app - that means different sets of data (tables, lists, etc.) that stretch horizontally and can be scrolled and can use the semantic zoom (which just shows the names of individual sections). I was trying to find some ways, but I have always found only examples using a list of same-type items, that are grouped somehow and shown in a GridView, but nothing similar to those built-in apps.

Thank you very, very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using ItemTemplateSelector. 
See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx